# Uniform circular motion [pendulum]

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Aga.jpg):I am quite confused about the direction of force R in this question.
Hope anyone could tell me some hint about the force.
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Aga.jpg]

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous question: [Uniform circular motion (pendulum)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537061/uniform-circular-motion-pendulum). Please do not repost closed questions! Instead, fix the original question so that it is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of R will be perpendicular to the surface of the cone with apex angle alpha.
The direction of normal reaction is always perpendicular to the concerned surface.
Therefore if you Break it in components along perpendicular axes 
You will get answer as B